# Request User to unlock screen once, Before receive call through CallKit

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, callkit

I need help to unlock screen programatically.

In my project, I am using webRTC and make peer to peer call, and Pushkit to notify enduser to join the call.

After receiving Pushkit, I am opening callkitUI Interface for user to accept and deny call. As my call is Video call, I need to open my application and load video screen,

Its working perfect if iPhone screen is not locked, But once screen is locked I am unable to open my app and redirect to video screen.

I want to unlock screen if its locked before user accept call through CallKit.

Comment: I am looking this feature for non jailbroken iPhone.

Comment: Similar how Skype or micro soft team done.

Comment: Looking for same solution?

Answer (score 0):

Let developers programmatically unlock the phone would be a gigantic security hole.

I'm not familiar with Skype or Microsoft Team, but if they work like WhatsApp, they use normal push notifications for video calls. When you receive a normal push and you tap on it, the app will be automatically opened if the phone is unlocked. If the phone is locked, the system asks you to unlock it (if you have Face ID you only have to watch the phone to unlock it, so it seems to be automatic but it isn't) and only when you unlock it you will see the app opened.